# How to add Doubleclick banner ad above Post Title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, double-click-advertising

I need to add a Doubleclick leaderboard ad above the Post in the center and above Category Titles in the center on my website. Is there a way to do this with the functions.php file? If not, another way without having to go into the wordpress core files? I don't want to have to redo it each time wordpress or the theme is updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've attached two screenshots to show you what I mean. Thanks again!!

[Screenshot Category Title](https://golfcartresource.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/category.jpg)

[Screenshot Post Title](https://golfcartresource.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Post.jpg)

Comment: What you're asking has nothing to do with changing WordPress core files. It's completely theme related. Changes to a theme should always be made to a child theme, so that you don't lose your work.  That being said, it is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Comment: Got it! Will do. Thanks for the reply, Justin!